# Using Angular and Ionic, how can I add elements to the DOM on a button click

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm working on an app using Ionic and Angular and would like the user to add input fields as they need. All tutorials I see on this topic are using Angular 1.x and I'm using Angular 4.

Here is the HTML:

```
<ion-content>

    <ion-row id="row" ng-repeat= "emailinput of emailinputs">
      <ion-col col-3 id="label">
        Email
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col col-8 id="emailcol">
        <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="jdoe@gmail.com" (keyup.enter)="Send($event.target.value)" [(ngModel)]="emailinput">
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>

  <div padding>
    <button (click) = "addnewemail(emailinput)" id="register" ion-button full color="nudgetprim" block>Add</button>
    <button (click) = "sendinvite(emailVal)" id="register" ion-button full color="nudgetprim" block>Invite</button>
  </div>

</ion-content>
```

The Typescript for the button is:

```
addnewemail(emailinput) {
    console.log(emailinput)
    var emailinputs = [];

    var newItem = emailinputs.length+1;
    emailinputs.push({'id' : 'row' + newItem, 'name' : 'row' + newItem});
}
```

Comment: you want to use `*ngFor` not `ng-repeat`. `ng-repeat is angular 1`....`*ngFor="let emailinput of emailinputs"`. also you dont want to declare `emailinputs = []` everytime the function is called you are emptying everything u added previously...`emailinputs` should be in the scope of the page so you can use it with `*ngFor`

Comment: ...im also realizing now you need to provide the type in your emailinput object so you can use it with `type=` and `id=`....and you will want the label to change so you can put {{emailinput.name}} there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what it should look like if I am interpreting what you want correctly. Your `id` and `name` attributes of an `emailinput` don't need to be there unless you have some use for them somewhere else.

```
<ion-content>

  <ion-item id="row" *ngFor="let emailinput of emailinputs ; let i = index">
    <ion-label>
      Email
    </ion-label>
    <ion-input type="email" id="email{{i}}" placeholder="jdoe@gmail.com" (keyup.enter)="Send($event.target.value)" [(ngModel)]="emailinput.email"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

  <div padding>
    <button (click) = "addnewemail()" id="register" ion-button full color="nudgetprim" block>Add</button>
    <button (click) = "sendinvite(emailVal)" id="sendinvite" ion-button full color="nudgetprim" block>Invite</button>
  </div>

</ion-content>
```

---

```
emailinputs = [{'id' : 'row0', 'name' : 'row0', 'email': ''}];

...

constructor(...

...

addnewemail() {
    let newItem = this.emailinputs.length;
    this.emailinputs.push({'id' : 'row' + newItem, 'name' : 'row' + newItem, 'email': ''});
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked!Could you explain how to explain how to pass `[(ngModel)]="emailinput.email"` into the `"sendinvite()"` function.

Comment: np, when u click send the invite is it only supposed to send the email associated with that block...if that is the case...you put the button inside `ion-item` and do `<button (click) = "sendinvite(emailinput.email)"` or maybe you want it to send invites to all of the emails?

Comment: Yes, I'd like that function to send invites to all entered emails!